# Error compiling CRF++ v0.51

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, crf++

I'm trying to compile CRF++ v0.51 which comes with ParsCit. `configure` does not show anything missing, however, when I try to `make` I get this error:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/to/parscit/crfpp/CRF++-0.51'
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -c -o node.lo node.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -c node.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/node.o
In file included from node.h:13:0,
                 from node.cpp:9:
path.h:26:52: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
make[1]: *** [node.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/parscit/crfpp/CRF++-0.51'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I was able to compile the newer version CRF++ v0.58 but ParsCit seems to need that v0.51.

Comment: I'm on the weird part of SO again. I mean, what this problem has to do with Perl?

Comment: ParsCit is mostly perl, so thought some may know whats wrong with the CRF++ version that comes with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers all around, I first added the import "stdlib.h" and import < iostream> lines to both node.cpp and path.cpp **at the end of the import list**. But it didn't work. Then (with some slight luck) thought to add the import lines at the start of the import list in both these files. And BRAVO!!!, it worked. CAUTION: I am not sure whether stdlib or iostream worked, but which one worked can be figured out easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `#include<iosteream>` in the 'node.cpp' file and compile crf++ again, as instructed in [troubleshooting](http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg/parsCit/#t) page.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Include the header file stdlib.h in path.h file.

It worked for me.